# Auto close a file opened in django __init__.py

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

I am creating a simple web application to search india pin codes (contained in a single csv file 'all_india_pin_code.csv'). This file is opened in `__init__.py` of my django app as below:

```
cf = open('all_india_pin_code.csv')
```

and this file handler is used in the app's views.py method like this:

```
cf.seek(0)
re = csv.reader(cf)
# more code here
```

Now, would this file be automatically closed when django development server (yet to use my app in production environment) is terminated with Ctrl+C? If not, what is the right way to do it? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you terminate the Django development server with `Ctrl+C`, this will kill the associated Python process and thus close all opened files.

To check this behavior, you can make the following test:

1. Start a Python interpreter and open a file:

   `open('all_india_pin_code.csv')`
2. In a shell, check that the file was opened by your Python process:

   `$ lsof | grep all_india_pin_code.csv`

   This will return you a result like:

   `python    26395       user    3r      REG              254,2         0   12217876 all_india_pin_code.csv`
3. Then kill the Python interpreter. For example:

   `$ kill -9 26395`
4. Check again if the file is opened. This command will return no result, because the file has been closed:

   `$ lsof | grep all_india_pin_code.csv`

Comment: Alexandre is right but I recommend you store the value in a string instead of keeping the file open. You're not gaining anything by keeping it open. Use `with open(...`, which will close when you read the content into a string. Also, There is inherent limitation in number of file descriptors that can be used by a process, so you're better off not using it when you don't need to.

Comment: Thanx Alexandre for the answer. But is it the right way to handle files? Is there a better way to do this in django environment?

Comment: Hi @Saikiran, the file is quite large (14M) with 154000+ records. Won't it lag performance due to large size when handled via string?

Comment: @Ganapathy: as your file is pretty big, I advise you to load it in memory because disk accesses are very slow. The simpler option is to use a global variable to store the content of your CSV file. Caveat: it is viable if you only need to retrieve values and not to modify them. You can define such a variable in the file where is your view, to collect in one place the data and logic about your file. For more complex use cases, you can use the Django's cache framework (e.g., if the content of your CSV file changes regularly). Do not hesitate to ask a new question if you need more help about this.

Comment: @Ganapathy: Moreover, as @Sairikan said, it is a good idea to use the context manager of files (``with open(...)``). This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way, to free up any system resources taken up by the open file.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment since my reputation is less than 50.
I want to add open the file in this way.

```
x = open('all_india_pin_code.csv')
```

And to check if your file is still open.
Just run `x.closed` it will return `False` if it is still open.
Then run `x.close()` to close it. Simple